# How to execute a script every time the terminal opens?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a script with welcome message that I want to execute every time the terminal opens. How can I do that? This is the script, what should I add so the script runs every time I open the terminal?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome to Linux Command Line Interface... "
echo -en '\n'
echo -en '\n'
dateAndTime=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H.%m')
echo "$dateAndTime"
```

Comment: Lower case `m` shows the month number in `date`.  I think you want uppercase `M` to show the minutes in your time.  Anyway, just add your script as the last line in the `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For us noobs :) in plain English:

1. Create your script and make a note of the full path
   *(I found it best to add it to the bin folder in the home directory, this way you can run your script without ./)*
2. Open Home folder in Nautilus and enable show hidden files
3. Open .bashrc in your text editor
4. Add the full path to your script to the end of the .bashrc
5. Save and exit

Answer (score 3):

Everything in you script except the shebang line can just be pasted into you `.bashrc` file at the end. Here's what I have in mine :

```
# Print "ubuntu" to terminal screen on startup
echo "            _                 _         "
echo "      _   _| |__  _   _ _ __ | |_ _   _ "
echo "     | | | | '_ \| | | | '_ \| __| | | |"
echo "     | |_| | |_) | |_| | | | | |_| |_| |"
echo "      \__,_|_.__/ \__,_|_| |_|\__|\__,_|"
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in multiple ways.

1. Probably the simplest one is to add call to your script at the end of `.bashrc` file, as stated in the comment. However, this will cause your script run not only when a terminal starts up, but also when you for example log in to the text console (reachable by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F4 for example), or when you log in remotely via ssh. If you don't use any of these, or if it is OK for you to run script in these cases also, then you don't need to look for other options :). If you however want the script to run **only** when terminal window is opened and not in any other case, then you can use one of the two other options:
2. You can add the line `bash -i` at the end of your script and then use the following command to start terminal: `gnome-terminal -e /path/to/your/script` (you may even edit the menu option that launches the terminal to include this parameter)
3. You can add the line `bash -i` at the end of your script (as in option 2) and then edit the default profile in the terminal. On the "Command" tab, check "Run custom command instead of shell" (the exact English wording may be a bit different, I'm using a non-English language version of Ubuntu), and below in the "Custom command" field, type the path to your script.

These are the methods that come to my mind right away. Probably there are more...

Answer (score -1):

Save your script in a directory such as `.dotfiles`. Then edit your shell's config file (eg. `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` and add `. .dotfiles/file.sh`. This will run your script every time a new shell is opened, regardless of your terminal.